# Xamarin visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Is Xamarin installer compatible with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and operating system Windows 7 x86 (32bit)?

Comment: Have you looked at their website?

Answer (score 1):

From the requirements page: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements

> Xamarin for Visual Studio supports any Visual Studio 2015 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise) and non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

You can use Xamarin for free with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition: https://www.xamarin.com/download